# Unity Engine "SendMessage has no receiver" Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
SendMessage ReceiveDamage has no receiver!
UnityEngine.Component:SendMessage (string,object)
Weapon:OnCollide (UnityEngine.Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Weapon.cs:56)
Collidable:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Collidable.cs:27)
Weapon:Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Weapon.cs:28)
```

[image: Error Image]
[image: Weapon Code Part 1]
[image: Weapon Code Part 2]
[image: Collide Code]

I have tried using `base.Update();` and just copying and pasting the code but the error still shows up.

I'm very new to game development and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.... I had put the enemy script on both the enemy and the enemies hitbox, removing it from the hitbox fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that no object is receiving the message you sent, because you are sending it through "coll", which is a `Collider2D`. You have to send it through the GameObject like this:

```
coll.gameObject.SendMessage("ReceiveDamage", dmg);
```

For this to work, the collided GameObject (which in this case is a "Fighter") must have a script attached to it that also has a function called `ReceiveDamage`.

You can learn more about this here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html

Comment: I do have a function in my Fighter script called ReceiveDamage, let me know if you see anything wrong with it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: protected virtual void ReceiveDamage(Damage dmg)
    {
        if (Time.time - lastImmune > immuneTime)
        {
            lastImmune = Time.time;
            hitpoint -= dmg.damageAmount;
            pushDirection = (transform.position - dmg.origin).normalized * dmg.pushForce;

            GameManager.instance.ShowText(dmg.damageAmount.ToString(), 30, Color.red, transform.position, Vector3.zero, 0.5f);

            if (hitpoint <= 0)
            {
                hitpoint = 0;
                Death();
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Did you try my proposed change?